# Count unique last entry of text across several columns

Tags: excel

I have an excel spreadsheet that lists locations across several columns.

I need to be able to count when certain conditions are matched.

My problem is that at the moment it is double counting when one of the criteria is listed in more than one column.

Example:

```
A      B      C       D        E
Green  Red   Green             Home
Green  Orange Red              Home
Orange                         Red
Red    Green                   SS
Green  Wait  Green            Home
```

So if i wanted to count how many occasions someone went from Green to Home the answer would be 2 However any of my COUNTIFS statements end up with 5 as they look at all the columns.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Document Here:
https://1drv.ms/x/s!AgGMgOrs2j1GgpR1BTbVpprPdrot7A

Comment: What formula have you tried that gives you the double counting?

Comment: =COUNTIFS(E3:E129, "Green", G3:G129, "Home")+ COUNTIFS(E3:E129, "Green", H3:H129, "Home")+COUNTIFS(E3:E129, "Green", K3:K129, "Home")+ COUNTIFS(G3:G129, "Green", H3:H129, "Home")+COUNTIFS(G3:G129, "Green", K3:K129, "Home")+ COUNTIFS(H3:H129, "Green", K3:K129, "Home")

Comment: The Columns that contain the location data are E, G, H, I and final location K

Comment: Please edit your original post to show a realistic data sample as well as your formulas.  The data sample you show seems inconsistent with what you posted in your comment above as to the locations of the data; what kind of data is in the intervening columns, and your formulas will be more readable in your original post.  Review the help topic for [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you for re formatting my original data example, i couldn't see a way to do it. The website seems unable to accept my screenshot of my data. The data in between the columns is time stamp information.

Comment: There's a help topic on Markdown.  There are also icons at the top of the edit box.  BTW, in  your formula above, you never examine column `I`; and also can someone go from Green to Home without Home being the final destination?

Comment: So far as screenshots, they are terrible to use for examples of your data.  It is not easy to get them into a screen shot.  **MUCH** better is posting as you did above, as a table.  Or you can use this [Markdown Table Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) but, after you paste in the table, you need to select the table, and use the "code sample" icon `{ }` on the edit bar.

Comment: The above should read "not easy to get a screen shot into an Excel worksheet"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not entirely clear to me exactly what you want, but given the table you have posted initially, with possible locations in columns `A:E`, the following will give a count of the number of rows that have `Green` followed by `Home` and blank entries will not be counted.

The formula is an array formula, and must be entered by holding down <kbd>ctrl + shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>

```
=SUM(N(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("greenhome",
CONCATENATE(IF(A2:A1000<>"",A2:A1000,""),
IF(B2:B1000<>"",B2:B1000,""),
IF(C2:C1000<>"",C2:C1000,""),
IF(D2:D1000<>"",D2:D1000,""))))))
```

> You can change the column references to whatever you want.
>
> A row will only be counted once, no matter how many sequences are noted.

If you use Named Ranges to contain your search phrases, then:

```
=SUM(N(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(From & To,
CONCATENATE(IF(A2:A1000<>"",A2:A1000,""),
IF(B2:B1000<>"",B2:B1000,""),
IF(C2:C1000<>"",C2:C1000,""),
IF(D2:D1000<>"",D2:D1000,""))))))
```

where, for example

> From refers to a cell that contains `Green`
>
> To refers to a cell that contains `Home`

**EDIT**:  Revised formula to account for the actual layout shown on your worksheet:

```
R2:  **from location**
S2:  **to location**

T2:   =SUM(N(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(R2&S2,
CONCATENATE(IF($E$2:$E$1000<>"",$E$2:$E$1000,""),
IF($G$2:$G$1000<>"",$G$2:$G$1000,""),
IF($H$2:$H$1000<>"",$H$2:$H$1000,""),
IF($I$2:$I$1000<>"",$I$2:$I$1000,""),
IF($K$2:$K$1000<>"",$K$2:$K$1000,""))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to email you? That way i could share the spreadsheet and you could see the requirements, i feel i'm not explaining it very well on here (plus you could then see the format of the data).

Comment: What happened when you adapted the formula to your actual columns? To share a file on this forum, create a workbook with sensitive information removed; upload it to some public file sharing site that does NOT require a registration for us to download from; and then share the link here (by editing your original post).  Post a comment here when you have done that so I will be notified.

Comment: Posted up a link to a reduced data set example.

Comment: @PeterD I adapted my formula to your data set layout and it seems to work fine.  What happened when you tried?  All you need to do is change the column references, and then change the addressing mode to absolute, so that it does not change when you fill down.

Comment: I'm just getting 0. I'm obviously doing something simple wrong. Could you save the spreadsheet back with how you've altered the formula?

Comment: @PeterD It won't let me edit your worksheet.  Says it is "locked".  I'll add the revised formula to my answer.

Comment: Odd - Its showing you have permission. This is the story of my life :o) I'll have a look at your edited formula once you've posted. Thanks for this.

Comment: The formulas are array formulas.  I have also added the instructions for how to properly enter them.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you for helping so much, its gratefully appreciated.